# Haskell function return values

Tags: haskell

what is the difference between

```
dotEx1 = map(+3) . filter (>100)
```

and

```
dotEx1 xs = map(+3) . filter (>100) xs
```

since

```
myFilter xs = filter (>100) xs
```

and

```
myFilter = filter (>100)
```

are the same why isn't

```
dotEx1 = map(+3) . filter (>100)
```

and

```
dotEx1 xs = map(+3) . filter (>100) xs
```

the same?

Comment: Because of the dot operator?

Comment: I feel like the extant answers don't actually address your question straight on: they say "how to fix it" but not "why it's wrong". The one-sentence answer to that part is pretty simple: function application has higher precedence than any infix operator, including `(.)`. (I don't really think this one sentence adds enough value to warrant putting in yet another answer, though.)

Answer (score 7):

The `.` function is defined as this:

```hs
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

The function composed by the `.` operator must accept an argument. Therefore,

```hs
dotEx1 = map(+3) . filter (>100)
```

Is the same as

```hs
dotEx1 xs = (map(+3) . filter (>100)) xs
```

Answer (score 4):

The dot operator has signature:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

here the operator is used *infix*. So in your first statement you have actually written:

```
dotEx1 = (.) (map (+3)) (filter (>100))
```

And that makes sense since `filter (>100)` has signature: `(Num n,Ord n) => [n] -> [n]` and `map (+3)` has signature `Num n => [n] -> [n]`. If you however write:

```
dotEx1 xs = (.) (map (+3)) (filter (>100) xs)
```

then `filter (>100) xs` has signature `(Num n,Ord n) => [n]` and so this is a value (not a function, or perhaps a function with no arguments). So the dot operator cannot be used (the types do not match).

Informally the dot operator should be given two functions `f` and `g` and it generates a function where `f` is applied *after* `g` is applied on the input. But `g` thus has to be a function taking one argument.

Answer (score 3):

The dot operator has low precedence because you want to partially apply functions. That is,

```
map (+3) . filter (>100)
```

is read as

```
(map (+3)) . (filter (>100))
```

By extension you get

```
dotEx1 xs = (map (+3)) . (filter (>100) xs)
```

instead of

```
dotEx1 xs = (map (+3) . filter (>100)) xs
```

A more readable version that also works:

```
dotEx1 xs = map (+3) . filter (>100) $ xs
```